# Integrating function f(x,y,z) over a rectangular prism

Tags: integration

I have a problem that I feel should be fairly straight-forwards, but I do not understand what I'm not doing correctly.
$$
f(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2\\
\text{With region: }0\le x\le2\text{ and }\:0\le y\le1\text{ and }0\le z\le4
$$
This should be easy enough to do. It's a rectangular prism and the function isn't very complex either, but the integral doesn't seem to be correct. I've done this multiple times, and I have only confirmed the same number which is not correct.
$$
\int_0^4\int_0^1\int_0^2 \left(x^2 + y^2 + z^2\right)\:dx\:dy\:dz\\
\int_0^4\int_0^1 \left[\frac{x^3}{3} + y^2x + z^2x\right]_0^2 \:dy\:dz\\
\int_0^4\int_0^1 \left(\frac{8}{3} + 2y^2 + 2z^2\right)\:dy\:dz\\
\int_0^4 \left[\frac{8}{3}y + \frac{2}{3}y^3 + 2z^2y\right]_0^1\: dz\\
\left[\frac{10}{3}z+\frac{2z^3}{3}\right]_0^4\\
\frac{40}{3}+\frac{128}{3} = \frac{168}{3} = 56
$$

Moreover, to my understanding, because this is a rectangular prism the order of integration should be arbitrary. I've integrated with different orders and gotten the same answer (which should be expected regardless due to the fact the variables all have the same power and coefficient.)

(I do understand that there are probably geometric ways of doing this, but for the sake of learning and preparing myself for my next midterm; I prefer to understand how to do the integral)

Where have I gone wrong?

UPDATE: I have fixed a small error in the entry above, and can confirm that it's correct with [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20integral%20of%20integral%20of%20x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%20%2B%20z%5E2%20dx%20dy%20dz%20from%200%20to%204%20from%200%20to%201%20from%200%20to%202). I think the problem is how I've setup the integral. I must be doing my regions wrong or something because I still can't figure it out.

Comment: Your solution seems to be OK. What is the "correct" andwer? But this is not a prism... Are you sure that the limits of the integrals don't contain variables?

Comment: In your fourth line you should have ${8\over3}y+{2\over3}y^3+2z^2y$. You forgot a factor of 2.

Comment: @zoli, unfortunately I don't know what the actual answer is. I enter it into my online homework and I get a correct or incorrect response.

Comment: @Aretino Following your prompt, I redid my work. I have corrected my entry above, but it is still not correct.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to read the actual homework question more thoroughly. Below is my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing incorrectly. Returning to the actual question I reread it and here was what I missed.

$$
... \text{Find the average value of the function } f(x,y,z)...
$$

This changes everything, because we're not looking for volume anymore. We're looking for the average value of the function.

The formula for average value of a function is
$$
\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x)\:dx
$$

So in this instance I needed to change my answer from $56$ to
$$
\frac{1}{4}*\frac{1}{2}*56 = 7
$$

Which is the correct answer for this homework problem.